# Check string with multiple if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried to check values of a dictionary within a for loop with an if statement that has multiple conditions.

First I tried this code which didn't work:

```
d = {2312: 'Jim', 2323: 'Anna', 2314: 'Tim', 3054: 'Marc', 3574: 'Valerie', 3698: 'Nina'}

Smith = list()
Miller = list()

for name in d.values():
    if name == 'Jim' or 'Anna' or 'Tim':
        Smith.append(name)
    else:
        Miller.append(name)

print(Smith)
print(Miller)
```

Then I tried this which worked:

```
d = {2312: 'Jim', 2323: 'Anna', 2314: 'Tim', 3054: 'Marc', 3574: 'Valerie', 3698: 'Nina'}

Smith = list()
Miller = list()

for name in d.values():
    if name == 'Jim' or name == 'Anna' or name == 'Tim':
        Smith.append(name)
    else:
        Miller.append(name)

print(Smith)
print(Miller)
```

My question is why does the first one not work but the second code does?

And is there a 'easier' code to check this?

Comment: This answers your questions: [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Comment: To answer your second question, "is there an easier way", yes! `if name in ("Jim", "Anna", "Tim")`